# bcdedit specified entry identifier not valid on command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, multi-boot, dualboot

**Context:** I have Ubuntu and Win11 installed, but I access directly to Win11.
If i run `bcdedit` I get:

```
Administrador de arranque de Windows
----------------------------------
Identificador           {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  es-MX
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {d44142df-8d25-11eb-ac07-f921b7a6bf92}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Cargador de arranque de Windows
-----------------------------
Identificador           {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  es-MX
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {d44142e2-8d25-11eb-ac07-f921b7a6bf92}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {d44142df-8d25-11eb-ac07-f921b7a6bf92}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
```

I think that running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} /set path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` should fix my problem (saw `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` with `bcdedit /enum all /v`), but I'm getting this error:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} /set path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
El comando de establecimiento especificado no es válido.
Ejecute "bcdedit /?" para obtener ayuda sobre la línea de comandos.
El parámetro no es correcto.
```

Which translates roughly to `bcdedit specified entry identifier not valid. Excecute "bcdedit /?" to get help about the command line. Parameter is not correct`.

I've tried this in command prompt and Powershell in admin mode.

Comment: `Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \foo\bar\buz.efi`
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcd-system-store-settings-for-uefi

u have redundant `/set`